# Javascript files could not be referenced in my pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I tried to reference the js files in my SharePoint pages but no way. I tried the follwing links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/customscriptfolder/scriptfile.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/SiteAssets/scriptfile.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Style Library/js/scriptfile.js" />
```

//and

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptExternalJs" runat="server"  Name="/Style Library/js/TestScript.js" Localizable="false" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="/scripts/TestScript.js"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ScriptLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.ASPX) with [URL tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to properly reference JavaScript files.

### Examples

To specify the URL of the parent site collection of the current website, use `~sitecollection` token:

```
 <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Script.js" runat="server"  />
```

To specify the URL of the current website, use `~site` token:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~site/SiteAssets/Script.js" runat="server"  />
```

To specify the URL of the Layouts virtual folder for the current website, use `~layouts` token:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~layouts/Contoso/Script.js" runat="server"  />
```

### References

[URLs and tokens in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831%28v=office.15%29.aspx)